# Second pass while using concat in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding

I'm converting a list of images to a Webm video using FFmpeg.

The current command is this (I'm calling it from my C# application):

```
-vsync 2 -safe 0 -f concat -i ".\concat.txt" -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 2M 
-pix_fmt yuv420p -vf "pad=width=1686:height=842:x=0:y=0:color=black" -y ".\Video.webm"
```

*(I'm using full paths in my app, as an example I'm using relative paths in here)*

I'm trying to improve the command by adding support to `-pass 2`, like this:

```
//First pass:
-vsync 2 -safe 0 -f concat -i ".\concat.txt" -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 2M -pix_fmt yuv420p 
-g 150 -tile-columns 6 -frame-parallel 1 -auto-alt-ref 1 -lag-in-frames 25 
-vf "pad=width=1686:height=842:x=0:y=0:color=black" -pass 1 -y ".\Video.webm"

//Second pass:
-vsync 2 -safe 0 -f concat -i ".\concat.txt" -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 2M -pix_fmt yuv420p 
-g 150 -tile-columns 6 -frame-parallel 1 -auto-alt-ref 1 -lag-in-frames 25 
-vf "pad=width=1686:height=842:x=0:y=0:color=black" -pass 2 -y ".\Video.webm"
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing the right thing. After the first pass, a ~625 bytes `Video.webm` file is created and after the second pass, the full video is created and plays normally.

Should I pass the `concat` param twice?
Should I set the output to the first pass with the same name as the second?

---

### Edit:

I also tried running 2-pass with mp4 and libx264, without success:

`[libx264 @ 0000024d719b4080] failed to rename "ffmpeg2pass-0.log.temp" to "ffmpeg2pass-0.log"`

```
//First pass:
-vsync 2 -safe 0 -f concat -i ".\concat.txt" -c:v libx264 -crf 30 -g 150 -pix_fmt yuv420p 
-vf "pad=width=1686:height=842:x=0:y=0:color=black" -pass 1 -y ".\Video.mp4"

//Second pass:
-vsync 2 -safe 0 -f concat -i ".\concat.txt" -c:v libx264 -crf 30 -g 150 -pix_fmt yuv420p 
-vf "pad=width=1686:height=842:x=0:y=0:color=black" -pass 2 -y ".\Video.mp4"
```

So I've tried to add `-passlogfile` using the same full path as the output file and it created a `*.log` and `*.log.mbtree` files on the output folder but the 2-pass simply fails.
I also tried to set the `-passlogfile` just to the first pass, no success.

### Edit 2:

2-pass does not accept `-crf`, so I replaced with `-b:v 2M`.

Now I just need to know if there's any switch in FFmpeg to erase the log files after the conversion. A `*.log` and `*.log.mbtree` are left behind.

### Edit 3

I have to remove the logs manually.

Comment: It's fine. 1st pass is only for analysis.

Comment: I guess the log file is created on the same folder as where the FFmpeg.exe file is located, right?

Comment: In working directory, which may not be where ffmpeg is located.